# Cannot set functionAppScaleLimit setting in Azure CLI for Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cli

I'm attempting to set the `functionAppScaleLimit`  to 1 according to the documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#limit-scale-out

Using the `az resource update --resource-type Microsoft.Web/sites -g <resource_group> -n <function_app_name>/config/web --set properties.functionAppScaleLimit=<scale_limit>` command appears like it's working, but if I look at the Azure Function app settings using `az resource show --ids <subscription_id>` the `functionAppScaleLimit` is set to `null.` After I do the `update` command, the output shows `properties.functionAppScaleLimit` is set to `1`. However, when I check with `az resource show` the `functionAppScaleLimit` setting appears to be in `properties.siteConfig.functionAppScaleLimit`.

Why do the settings look different after the update and when I check with `az resource show`? If I try to update instead using `--set properties.siteConfig.functionAppScaleLimit=1` I get an error. I'll be doing some testing to see if the setting is actually working, but this seems a little strange.

Comment: It seems the command works in your description. What do you mean when you  update without using `--set` option getting an error?

Comment: when I check the properties using `resource show`, I don't see the `functionAppScaleLimit` under `properties`, it's under `properties.siteConfig` and is set to `null`. I actually found that I can see the setting in the UI under the "Scale Out` tab and it's correctly set to `1`. Just weird that `resource show` doesn't show it.

Comment: Do you use `az resource show --resource-type Microsoft.Web/sites -g <ResourceGroup> -n <FunctionName>/config/web`?

Comment: that worked, thanks @Doris Lv. Do you know why it shows different settings when I use `az resource show --ids <subscription_id>`?

Comment: I have generate my reply to an answer, would you mind accept it as the answer for others to refer? @John T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the **format** of `az resource show` is **different**, sorry I didn't find the reason, but we can sure that we can do this command to limit scale out:

```
az resource update --resource-type Microsoft.Web/sites -g <resource_group> -n <function_app_name>/config/web --set properties.functionAppScaleLimit=<scale_limit>
```

for ensuring it works or not, better use portal or the command I post instead `--ids` option.

```
az resource show --resource-type Microsoft.Web/sites -g <ResourceGroup> -n <FunctionName>/config/web
```